# Upgrade to PHP5 on Plesk 8.0: is my webhost full of it?

Tags: php, hosting, plesk

I asked my host to upgrade from an old PHP4 version to the latest PHP version available 5.x.x (?) and they told me I need to pay for a new server because they can't upgrade to PHP5 on Plesk 8.0.

My question is: shouldn't they be able to upgrade Plesk on the current server and then upgrade to PHP5?

Comment: What does it matter? They wont do it. So if you want it either change hosting or pay for the new server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [answer](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=531995) on google.